Why NaCN is not soluble in DMSO?
Wikipedia article about sodium cyanide states that it is not soluble in dimethyl sulfoxide. This seems counterintuitive and I want to know if this is actually true statement and if yes then why? Since DMSO is polar solvent it should be able to dissolve ionic compounds.

Sodium compounds like NaCl or others are sparsely soluble in DMSO.

@Maurice What's wrong with sodium?

This table says it's slightly soluble in ethanol and formamide. I think it's the protic aspect that is important here. Overall the solubilities of salts in polar organic solvent are usually pretty low.

There is nothing wrong with sodium salts, The weak solubility in DNSO is also observed with other inorganic salts, like potassium salts. Probably DMSO is not polar enough for dissolving inorganic salts.

This pdf says 1g / 100 mL - rather slightly soluble - insoluble would be an overstatement, though.
